# Angular JS cookies working fine with Chrome but not with Mozilla Firefox

Tags: cookies

Angular JS cookies working fine with Chrome but not with Mozilla Firefox.

We did write below code for reading/writing cookies -

Writing cookie - $cookies.user_id = "test user id";
Reading cookie - var user_id = $cookies.user_id;

Scripts used -

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try using it a bit different way. Way for adding a new cookie:

```
$cookies.put('cookiesAccepted', true, {path:'/'});
```

and here's for removing:

```
$cookies.remove('cookiesAccepted', {path: '/'});
```

Don't forget to add the object (`{path:'/'}`) as third parameter for `put`, and as a second parameter for `remove`, otherwise it won't work with FireFox.